# Are there any arduino ethernet shield or libraries for IPv6?

Tags: arduino, ipv6

I'm new to arduino and I'm trying to use IPv6 with arduino UNO and ethernet shield(W5100).

I have found EtherSia IPv6 (https://github.com/njh/EtherSia) library and run **MiniHTTPServer.ino** sketches.

The serial monitor always print link-local address. I can't find a way to set global address.

```
[EtherSia MiniHTTPServer]
Failed to configure Ethernet
Our link-local address is: fe80:0000:0000:0000:9cb3:19ff:fec7:1b10
Our global address is: 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000
Ready.
```

Any suggestions for IPv6 ethernet shield or IPv6 library for Arduino?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EtherSia library says that it does **NOT** support DHCPv6.

You may want to check if your local network environment is configured with DHCPv6.

"**PHPoC Shield for Arduino**" may be what you are looking for. Of course, it supports IPv6 including DHCPv6.You can get the detailed information about this library from the below.

- download https://github.com/phpoc/arduino
- manual http://www.phpoc.com/support/manual/phpoc_shield_for_arduino_library_reference/

Just check "**ChatServerIPv6**" sketch for testing IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

EtherSia indeed does not support DHCPv6, but it does support SLAAC - Stateless Auto-configuration, which is widely supported and enabled by routers.

What type of router do you have?

An alternative is to configure the address and router statically:

```
// Configure a static global address and router addresses
ether.setGlobalAddress("2001:1234::5000");
if (ether.setRouter("fe80::f4c0:4ff:fefb:4186") == false) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure router address");
}
```

This is from the example here:

https://github.com/njh/EtherSia/blob/master/examples/MinimalStatic/MinimalStatic.ino